# Re-enter Italy from India after 7.5 years

Tags: indian-citizens, italy

In October 2011 I had to leave Italy due to some family issues. At that time I was working and having Permesso di soggorno as well with (Carta di identita e Patante di Guida).

Now as you can understand my all documents are expired. I want to know is there any way or procedure using which I can return to Italy and start working again?

Comment: The right direction would be to reapply for a work permit in Italy through employment or as a student. Citizens of non-Schengen countries can apply for a Schengen National visa to migrate to Italy. https://www.immigrationworld.com/italy/how-to-migrate-to-italy/ . You should ask on the expatriates site.

Comment: Questions about long term stay and working generally fall in the ambit of ExpatriatesSE. I've flagged it as off-topic. Hopefully, mods will migrate it to the correct forum.

Comment: Here is a link to [Expatriates.SE].